# Prove that the class of CFG languages that are closed under reversal is undecidable

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, undecidability

### Note

The wording of the title may be a bit vague, but I'm not asking if CFLs are closed under reversal. Please see below.

### Problem Description

Given a word $w$, define $w^{r}$ to be its reversal.

Let $L=\{ G \vert G \text{ is a } CFG \text{ and for every } w \in L(G), w^{r} \in L(G) \}$

Prove that $L$ is undecidable.

### My Attempt

I am aware that I should reduce a known-to-be-undecidable language to L, but by looking at the four undecidable languages [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Decidability) (Equivalence, Disjointness, Containment, Universality), I still failed to determine which language I can use. Please guide me a direction, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G_1,G_2$ be two context-free grammars. We can construct a context-free grammar $G$ such that
$$
L(G) = \#L(G_1) \cup L(G_2)^r\#,
$$
where $\#$ is a new symbol. The language $L(G)$ is closed under reverse iff $L(G_1) = L(G_2)$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But what if $L(G_{1})=\{a\}$ and $L(G_{2})=\emptyset$? In this case, $L(G)=\{\#a\#\}$  is closed under reversal, but $L(G_{1}) \neq L(G_{2})$.

Comment: In your case, $L(G) = \{\#a\}$, which isn’t closed under reversal.